# I used to get a quotes from the API quotes by using fetch method but no results found

Tags: javascript, get, fetch-api

I have a function to get a random quote from an API.quotes Help me avoid the result `undefined`.

```js
function getQuote() {
  return fetch('https://type.fit/api/quotes').then(response => {
    return response.json()
  }).then(jsonResponse => {
    if (!jsonResponse.length) {
      return []
    }
    return jsonResponse[Math.floor(Math.random() * jsonResponse.length)]
  })
}
const textQuote = getQuote().text;
const authorQuote = getQuote().author;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this comes down to a better [understanding of promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). `getQuote` will return a promise because [`fetch` returns a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). You can then use `.then()` chaining to get the result of your function, which is your quote object.

Also

```
const textQuote = getQuote().text;
const authorQuote = getQuote().author;
```

won't work because you are calling the method twice (which, if it worked would mean you would get 2 different quotes returned that won't match).

In the example below you can see that `getQuote` is only called once and then is chained with a `.then` to handle the result.

```js
function getQuote() {
  return fetch('https://type.fit/api/quotes').then(response => {
    return response.json()
  }).then(jsonResponse => {
    if (!jsonResponse.length) {
      return []
    }
    return jsonResponse[Math.floor(Math.random() * jsonResponse.length)]
  })
}

getQuote().then(quote => {
  const text = quote.text;
  const author = quote.author;
  console.log(text, author)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry my friend i have changing my code to be very simple and usefull promise so i do like this:

```
 const getQuote = async function()  {
let response = await fetch('https://type.fit/api/quotes',{method: 'GET'});
let quotes = await response.json();
console.log(quotes)
let indexQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
let quote = quotes[indexQuote];
console.log(quote)
return {
   text: quote.text;
   author: quote.author
}
  
 }
 const quote1 = getQuote().then((quote) => {console.log(quote)}).catch((error)=> {
    console.log(error)
 })
```